# Emails to an alias forwarded to Gmail account not received

Tags: gmail

I own a domain but use Gmail as my email account. I have 4 addresses as email aliases that forward messages to my Gmail account.

Recently I stopped receiving them, including to my spam folder. I verified with my host that the emails are being received and sent.

Does anybody have any ideas to help fix this issue?

Comment: Could you post the relevant log file entries generated by your SMTP server?

Comment: I sent from a Hotmail account to test as I assume Microsoft accounts should be trustworthy (meaning they are less likely to be on a black list used by my domain or Gmail). Is there a way to get that information from Hotmail?

Comment: Not in spam? Any filters which might be acting on them?

Comment: And just to confirm, you're forwarding them from somewhere else and you've confirmed that they're leaving there, _not_ that you're having Gmail retrieve the messages (via POP3), right?

Comment: On the filters page in your settings there's also a spot for blocked addresses. (This is a relatively new feature.) Make sure you haven't blocked yourself.

Comment: Are your four other email addresses (The aliases) also GMail accounts?

Comment: @AlE.Not in spam, no filters on the gmail account, no blocked addresses. Yes, my webhost confirms the emails arrive and are sent to the gmail address.

Comment: @Dale No, they are aliases at my own domain

Comment: This might help.  GMail does have some restrictions about how much email can be received over a given amount of time.  Something you might want to look into.  https://support.google.com/a/answer/1366776?hl=en&ref_topic=6013516&vid=0-635810253314933439-1266103612

Comment: @Dale I am definitely not hitting that limit, but that is good to know

Comment: Have you tried turning off the forwarding and simply having other accounts on a different domain do a forward to that email address?  Maybe even trying having the account forward an email to itself.  Maybe it has something to do with the domain that the emails are being sent from.

Comment: @Dale I have considered that, although I was trying to avoid that as it is more complicated to setup. A fallback option for sure

Comment: I was thinking about that just for analysis sake.  This might shine some light on what is going on.  It might not be a solution however it might point to either the domain setup or your gmail account accordingly.

Comment: Ok, so I finally got the emails after more than 24 hours. So the problem has changed to why the huge delay... and who caused it.